# Firefox 68: local files now treated as cross-origin; is there a way to override?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Firefox 68 fixes a security problem with local files (https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730), but in so doing breaks testing code locally. Is there a way to override this as can be done with Chrome and Opera (e.g., --allow-file-access-from-files)?

I cannot find anything relevant on the Firefox site, and cannot find a suitable command-line option or anything in about:config.

```
try {
    main = opener.document;
    }
    catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.name);
    }
}
```

I get the following messages in the console:

```
DOMException: "Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object"
SecurityError
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### [2023 Update]: This pref has been removed since this answer was posted. See [user3611642's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71676463/3702797) for an up to date solution].

Letting the original answer if someone comes back to using FF68 and faces this issue.

---

You can leverage this restriction by going to `about:config` url and then uncheck `privacy.file_unique_origin` boolean value.

However be aware that this only reverts to *< 68* protection mode, which is to only allow digging in, even with this flag down you won't be able to fetch `../some_other_dir/foo.bar`.

Comment: Just tried your solution. It works. And it *does* fetch from ../some_other_dir/foo.bar

Comment: This doesn't work as of at least 2023, probably sooner. See the other answer for an up-to-date configuration flag to flip.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @TomášHübelbauer added a note pointing to the other answer.

Answer (score 15):

In my case: Firefox ver. 98.0.2 (64-bit) going to `about:config` and changing the flag helped:
`security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` = `false`

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy over `privacy.file_unique_origin` not working anymore! Also note that restart is not required and this is the only setting you need to switch as of today, `privacy.file_unique_origin` is not needed/supported anymore.